# Translating a view and the rotating it problem

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-graphics, translation

I have a custom UIImageView, I can drag it around screen by making a translation with (xDif and yDif is the amount fingers moved):

```
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xDif, yDif);
[self setTransform: CGAffineTransformConcat([self transform], translate)];
```

Let's say I moved the ImageView for 50px in both x and y directions. I then try to rotate the ImageView (via gesture recognizer) with:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([recognizer rotation]);
myImageView.transform = transform;
```

What happens is the ImageView suddenly moves to where the ImageView was originally located (before the translation - not from the moved position + 50px in both directions).

(It seems that no matter how I translate the view, the self.center of the ImageView subclass stays the same - where it was originally laid in IB).

Another problem is, if I rotate the ImageView by 30 deg, and then try to rotate it a bit more, it will again start from the original position (angle = 0) and go from there, why wouldn't it start from the angle 30 deg and not 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the earlier transform. To add to the current transform, you should do this –

```
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(myImageView.transform, recognizer.rotation);
```

Since you're changing the `transform` property in a serial order, you should use `CGAffineTransformRotate`, `CGAffineTransformTranslate` and `CGAffineTransformScale` instead so that you add to the original transform and not create a new one.

Comment: As for the `center` part, it doesn't change and another thing to note is that `frame` will become unreliable when altering the `transform` property.

Comment: Why wouldn't the center change, when clearly the view is not where it was at the beginning after the translation...

Comment: Oh, so what they do is leave all the initial data like center the same always and always transform them with a transform matrix to get the new position...

Comment: [`Documentation on transform`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW4). The basis of the transform is the `center` itself. Although you are right in saying that it is not the true center anymore. Theoretically, `CGPointApplyAffineTransform` should help you get the true center but it occasionally seems to give the wrong center.

Comment: Yes, I didn't see your last comment but glad we agree on it now.

Comment: And I also tried the solution you proposed earlier also, what it does is, if I rotate just a little bit, it works, but if I wanted let's say rotate the view by 90 deg, it will instead rotate it by 360 or even more.

Comment: Are you doing `recognizer.rotation = 0;` at the end of the gesture handler? Otherwise it gets invoked many times during the rotation and `recognizer.rotation` has the rotation since the gesture was started and not when it was last called.

Comment: Take a look at this video, and you will see what happens: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMvl17qHMVg

Comment: I am pretty sure my last comment holds.

Comment: AAAAAhh, solved it, when I did the Transformation (rotation) I had to reset the recognizer.rotation to 0! Thanx Deepak!